# Aumentar tamanho do icone na aba do navegador

Tags: html, html5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de aumentar um pouco o tamanho do meu icone na aba do navegador, como comparativo anexei a imagem e como podem ver está menor do que o padrão.

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/m8.ico" />
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho da sua logo ? sinceramente eu não consegui notar muita  diferença .. já tentou redimensionar em algum programa editor de imagens ? esse icon do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ por exemplo e 32x32

Comment: Tentei redimensionar sim.. mas nada mudou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/m8.ico" sizes="16x16">
```